# How to send an email using Go with an HTML formatted body?

Tags: email, go

This seems like a very common need, but I didn't find any good guides when I searched for it.

Comment: This is an addendum to @GreyHands answer: I was having the issue where **even after setting the MIME / Content Type my html tags were showing as plain text**. Turns out I had imported `html/template` and the escaping resulted in the html appearing as plain text. Importing `text/template`, instead, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 76):

Assuming that you're using the net/smtp package and so the smtp.SendMail function, you just need to declare the MIME type in your message.

```
subject := "Subject: Test email from Go!\n"
mime := "MIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\n"
body := "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>"
msg := []byte(subject + mime + body)

smtp.SendMail(server, auth, from, to, msg)
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 30):

I am the author of [gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/). With this package you can easily send HTML emails:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "alex@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "bob@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
    m.SetBody("text/html", "Hello <b>Bob</b>!")

    // Send the email to Bob
    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

You can also add a plain text version of the body in your email for the client that does not support HTML using the method [AddAlternative](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Message.AddAlternative).

Comment: Da best wrapper I've seen so far. Highly recommended.

Comment: I questioned the necessity of a wrapper given the equivalence of the golang core library function, but reviewing your GitHub repo, I see you've developed a rich package. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Not actively maintained anymore unfortunately.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about gomail is that, when you set the 'Sender' in header, the 'Return-Path' appears as header in outlook.